# Can I move the fairie on a bonus turn due to the builder?

Tags: carcassonne, expansions

I was playing Carcassonne with both the Traders & Builders and the Princess & Dragon expansions. Traders & Builders adds the builder meeple, which gives a bonus turn if a tile is added to a city or road the builder is on. Princess & Dragon adds the fairie, which can be moved if you do not place or move a meeple on your turn.

Let's say I place a tile onto a city (or road) which has my builder in it, and place a meeple on this new tile. This gives me a bonus turn. I place a second tile (anywhere else, it doesn't matter), but don't place a meeple on it. Can I move the fairie, since I didn't place a meeple on the second tile? Or, does placing the meeple on the first tile count as moving a meeple for the purposes of the fairie. Alternatively, let's say I moved the fairie after placing the first tile; am I now prohibited from placing a meeple on the second tile?

One advantage of the fairie is that it gives you a point at the beginning of your turn if you control it. The rules for Princess & Dragon explicitly state that you don't get 2 points if you get a bonus turn from the builder, but don't say anything about the situation above, that I could see.

Answer (score 4):

A player may move the fairy instead of placing a follower.

A player can move the fairy on the placement of the first tile, the second tile, or both.

A player can only score the one point when the turn begins.  The "double turn" is a continuation of the turn, not the beginning of a new turn.  Therefore a player cannot move the fairy on the first tile and then score the one point.

Comment: I agree with this answer, it's not a second turn, but a second tile in the first tun.